# WF4 sql persistence error

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4

I am trying to use SQLPersistence in my workflow. The document I am following is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee395773(v=vs.100).aspx

When I invoke the workflow, I keep getting the error "Procedure or function 'CreateLockOwner' expects parameter '@serviceDeploymentHash', which was not supplied."

Googled this but I could not find any solutions.

Comment: Haven't you created the databases with SQL scripts for .NET Framework 4.5? I'm not seeing that *@serviceDeploymentHash* input parameter on *CreateLockOwner* on 4.0 scripts.

Comment: I downloaded these WF samples from MS and ran the scripts from that instead of the ones located in the framework folder. I shall try the scripts from the framework and report back

Comment: Thanks Jota. It was indeed the wrong version of the scripts I had run the first time around.